# Determine the source port of an IPv4 packet with perl

Tags: linux, perl, ip, tun

I have a perl script that reads and processes IPv4 packets from a TunTap interface. Stripped down a bit, it looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Common;
use Linux::TunTap;
use NetPacket::IP;
use IO::Socket;
$|++;

###### Predecs #####
my $tun;
my %config = Loadconfig();

$tun = Linux::TunTap->new(NAME => $config{'localtun_name'})
or die "Couldn't connect to Interface $config{localtun_name}\n";
print "Interface up: " . $tun->{interface} . "\n";

while (my $rawdata = $tun->get_raw()) {
        $rawdata =~ s/^....//; # Strip the TunTap header
        my $packet = NetPacket::IP->decode($rawdata);
        print "$packet->{id} $packet->{src_ip} -> $packet->{dest_ip} $packet->{proto} $packet->{len}\n";
        # Do some processing here
}
```

For routing reasons, I need to know the source port of the data. I have not found a way of doing this with `NetPacket::IP`, so is there a different way of determining this? I am currently only using `NetPacket::IP` for debugging reasons, so I am not really set on that module in particular if a different module will allow me to extract the source port in addition to sequence number, size, source IP, and destination IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NetPacket::IP` only deals with IP packets which have no concept of ports. Ports only come into play on the TCP/UDP (or whatever you have layered on top of IP) layer, so you need e.g. `NetPacket::TCP` to get this information. You'll probably have to look at $packet->{proto} to decide which module (TCP or UDP) you want to use for the layer4 parsing.

If you're sure you won't need additional header fields for which the higher-level `NetPacket` modules would make sense, you could exploit the fact that the source port is in the first 16 bits of the header both for TCP and UDP, so you could say

```
# Untested, so I'm not sure about the case returned in
# $packet->{proto}
if($packet->{proto} eq 'tcp' or $packet->{proto} eq 'udp') {
    $port = unpack('n', $packet->{data});
    ...
}
```

Edit: BTW, using substr() instead of a regexp substitution should be faster if that's a concern.

Comment: Cheers, will test tonight if this does what I need, and reevaluate moving my entire project a layer down in the model

Comment: Alright, had a go at this. I am now able to extract the src_port from the other modules (`NetPacket::TCP` and `NetPacket::UDP`). As for the code snippet, `$packet->{proto}` returns a protocol number (6 for TCP), so only a slight alteration there, however, the result from `unpack('n', $packet->{data});`is different from what I get by doing `$tcppacket->{'src_port'}`. Any chance the unpack function is used incorrectly? When testing on an ICMP packet, which shouldn't have a source port, that `unpack()`-line yelds 2048

Comment: What exactly are you getting from `unpack()` and `$tcppacket->{src_port}` respectively? If you look at `NetPacket::TCP::decode()`, you'll find they do it exactly like this, just with more fields:
        `($self->{src_port}, $self->{dest_port}, $self->{seqnum}, 
         $self->{acknum}, $tmp, $self->{winsize}, $self->{cksum}, 
         $self->{urg}, $self->{options}) =
             unpack("nnNNnnnna*", $pkt);`

That you're getting a bogus value from an ICMP packet is simply because you're decoding the Type and Code fields that are in the same place as the port number in TCP/UDP.

Comment: Upon testing with a telnet connection, the `unpack()` method gives 45696, while `$packet->{src_port}` gives 17680. However, I'm using `unpack()` on the raw data as provided by `Linux::TunTap` while stripping the first 7 bytes, and `$packet->{src_port}` is using a `NetPacket::TCP` object created from said raw data with the `NetPacket::TCP->decode()` method. Perhaps I'm going about this incorrectly?

Comment: No, that can't be correct. Why 7 bytes? An IPv4 header is between 20 and 60 bytes long, depending on the options. You could check with tcpdump or wireshark to see which port value is correct.

Comment: TunTap adds an additional 7 byte header that has to be removed for the raw data to be parseable by the modules. If it isn't removed, `decode()` returns garbage.

Comment: The header is four bytes; above you had it stripped correctly. But then you're still at the start of the IP header, not the TCP/UDP one. Try and make it work with `NetPacket::IP` first before you attempt to optimize it.